# Prove that $x^2y^2(4-x^2)(4-y^2) \leq16$ for all $|x|\leq2$ and $|y| \leq 2$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Prove that $x^2y^2(4-x^2)(4-y^2) \leq16$ for all $|x|\leq2$ and $|y| \leq 2$

**My attempt:**

If $x^2(4-x^2) \leq 4$ for $|x|\leq2$ and $y^2(4-y^2) \leq 4$ for $|y|\leq2$ then the inequality holds.

Define $h(x) = x^2(4-x^2)-4$. $h'(x) = 8x-4x^3$, hence we get critical points $x=0,\pm \sqrt{2}$. By the second derivative test we find that $0$ is a maximum in the $|x| \leq 2$ range  . Hence:

$$x^2(4-x^2)-4 \leq 0$$
$$x^2(4-x^2)\leq 4$$

A similar argument for the $y$ based function, and hence the top inequality holds.

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: You'd also need to show that $  0 \leq x^2 (4-x^2)$, to justify multiplying the inequalities.

Comment: No need for calculus here; $x^2(4-x^2)\le4$ by the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means): $\sqrt{x^2(4-x^2)}\le\frac{x^2+(4-x^2)}2=2$

Comment: Did you mean that $0$ is a *minimum*?

Comment: Yes it is.${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(x^2-2)^2 \geq0 
\Rightarrow (x^2)^2-4x^2+4 \geq0 
\Rightarrow (x^2)^2-4x^2 \geq-4 
\Rightarrow 4x^2-(x^2)^2 \leq4 \\
\Rightarrow x^2(4-x^2) \leq4
$$
Similarely $y^2(4-y^2) \leq4$.

When $0<y<x$ and $0<z<t$, then $0<yz<xt$. Now we have $x^2(4-x^2) \leq4$ and $y^2(4-y^2) \leq4$, and hence $x^2y^2(4-x^2)(4-y^2) \leq16$.

Answer (score 3):

Note

$$x^2y^2(4-x^2)(4-y^2)=[4-(2-x^2)^2][4-(2-y^2)^2]\le4\cdot4=16
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(\frac x2\right)^2\left(\frac y2\right)^2\left(1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2\right)\left(1-\left(\frac y2\right)^2\right)\le \frac{1}{16}
$$

now make the substitutions

$$
\cases {
\frac x2=\sin a\\
\frac y2=\sin b
}
$$

then

$$
\left(\frac 12\sin(2a)\right)^2\left(\frac 12\sin(2b)\right)^2\le\frac{1}{16}
$$